# Jquery object hover object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a table with `z-index = 10` . Also I have an image(.gif) with `z-index = 100`. The image is moving from left to right by using :

```
$('#misil').animate({'margin-left':'1250px'},1700});
```

Now I want every cell the image steps by, make some animation, maybe somethis like

```
 $('#cell').animate({'opacity':'1250px'},400});
```

Answer (score 0):

The only way I can think to do this is to continuously compare the position of the image to the position of every single cell. This would be extremely taxing to the browser, but I think it's really your only option. Something like this:

```
setInterval(function(){
    var imgpos = $('#misil').offset().left;
    var imgwidth = $('#misil').width();
    $('table .cell').each(function(){
        var cellpos = $(this).offset().left;
        var cellwidth = $(this).width();
        if( cellpos <= imgpos && (cellpos + cellwidth) <= (imgpos) )
        {
            $(this).animate({opacity: 1},400)
        }
    })
},10)
```

The above code would make each cell animate to full opacity during the time that the image is over it.

Your code is a little weird (you can't animate opacity using a pixel value, etc), but I think I understood your question.